# Cannot access to custom object which added to collection in custom class via method

Tags: vba, class

I have a custom class **List**:

```vb
Private me_col As New Collection

Public Function GetAt(position As Integer)
    GetAt = me_col(position + 1)
End Function

Public Sub Add(value)
    me_col.Add value
End Sub
```

If I add a list directly to the collection, I can get it via index. The message box will show "List":

```vb
Sub Run()
Dim col As New Collection

Dim child As New List

col.Add child
MsgBox TypeName(col(1))
End Sub
```

But if I try add it to the List via `List.Add` and `GetAt` later, the application will throw a **Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method**:

```vb
Sub Run()
Dim col As New List

Dim child As New List

col.Add child
MsgBox TypeName(col.GetAt(0))
End Sub
```

This work well with primitive values, only fail on objects such as custom class.

```vb
col.Add "a primitive value"
MsgBox TypeName(col.GetAt(0)) 'String
```

Comment: The class exposes `Add` method and you use `col.AddNew child`. Then,  you did not add anything in `child` and even if you would do it, you called it in an inappropriate way. It should be a collection in a collection...

Comment: I'm sorry, I must retype this on another machine. It's just a typo, I will edit the question, but the error are the same.

Comment: So, your class have to be adapted to also return objects. The class member cannot be returned as string. You should, in fact I will try posting a relevant answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next approach:

1. Adapt the "List" class code in this way:

```
Option Explicit

Private me_col As New Collection

Public Function GetAt(position As Integer) As Variant
   If IsObject(me_col(position + 1)) Then
        Set GetAt = me_col(position + 1) 'for the case of an object member (class, collection, sheet etc.)...
    Else
       GetAt = me_col(position + 1)
    End If
End Function

Public Sub Add(value)
    me_col.Add value
End Sub
```

2. Test it in the next way:

```
Sub RunList()
 Dim col As New List, child As New List
 child.Add "first item" 'place an item in the first class collection
 
 col.Add child          'place the class inside the class
 col.Add "second item"  'place a string like the second element
 col.Add Array("third item", "fourth item") 'add an array like the third element
 
 MsgBox col.GetAt(0).GetAt(0) 'being a class, you should return the string in the appropriate way...
 MsgBox col.GetAt(1)     'returning the string entry/element
 MsgBox col.GetAt(2)(0)  'returning the first element of the array element...
End Sub
```

Please, test it, try understanding its meaning and send some feedback.

Comment: @Trần Hoàn Didn't you try the above solution? If tried, still unclear how to use such a class for the purpose you put in discussion?

Comment: This worked. Before asking this, I have searched for more than 3 hours. and found something like assign to array, but not function. Seems like every time I try assign some object to a variable, I must set reference, even with function returning. VB is so strange for me, I worked with some other languages (most are Java, C#, JS) but nothing is like this one.

Comment: @Trần Hoàn In VBA you **must** use `Set` **for any object**. The rest works in a similar way regarding other languages... The main idea when 'read' the return, is to use a property/method the object has/exposes...